# ASP.NET MVC - send int in create view and capture it in hidden field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 Tables: tblClient and tblActivity.

tblClient's Primary Key is an int called clientID.

tblActivity has a Foreign Key of the same nature (int clientID)

What I'm trying to do is make a Create View for a tblActivity Record,
that captures the clientID of the Client who is currently watching his list of Activities and inputs it in the form.

I already have the list of activities view.

I've been having troubles with understanding how to send an int to my View from the `Get` Method for the Activity in my controller, and how to make the `@Html.hiddenFor` in my view to capture it and send it back to the `Post` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view model for this view

```
public class CreateActivity
{
  public int ClientId { set;get;}
  public string Title { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your create view, accept the client id in the url, create an object of CreateActivity view model, set the ClientId property value and send that to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
  var vm = new CreateActivity { ClientId = id };
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your view

```
@model CreateActivity
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Title)
  @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.ClientId)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Since `ClientId` is stored in as hidden form field, it will be available when you submit the form.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateActivity model)
{
  // check model.ClientId 
  // to do  : Return something
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt help!!! i managed to do something with viewbags to solve my question, but i am definitely going to see if your solution worked too!